# dropdown menu without hidden rows how to ignore the hidden ones?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a list with hidden rows and want to make a dropdown menu without the hidden ones. How can i do this so that the dropdown only uses the not hidden rows/cells?

If i filter the rows to my criterias and i want to make a dropdown menu with the rest of the cells from the not hidden rows. it also uses the hidden rows. what i don't want.
I can't delete the hidden rows. and only copying the hole stuff without the hidden ones is not the best idea.

so does anyone has an idea how my dropdown menu can ignore hidden rows/ cells?

please help me :) thanks

Comment: with "dropdown menu" ... do you mean an in-cell drop down as in "Data/Validation"?

Comment: I mean "Data/Validation". sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

A range being the source of data validation of type "List" doesn't react on hidden rows.

What you can do is to

- create an original list of values (including a header allowing for AutoFilter)
- create another range that holds only the filtered/displayed values of the original list and serves as the actual data validation source
- run a VBA which copies only non-hidden rows from original to filtered list

In below example, named range List_of_Values contains all possible choices and a column heading with Autofilter just ABOVE, named range `FilteredList` originally is just one empty cell with plenty of space below, and the data validation setting is Allow -> `List` / Source -> `=FilteredList`

Now you apply any Filter to the original list and by any means (a button, an event like sheet.deactivate, or just Developer/Macros/Run etc.) you start Sub Update_LOV which will copy only non-hidden rows from Original to filtered/validation list.

```
Sub Update_LOV()
Dim R_Filt As Range, R_Orig As Range, Idx As Integer, Jdx As Integer

    Set R_Orig = Range("List_of_Values")
    Set R_Filt = Range("FilteredList")
    Idx = 1
    Jdx = 1

    R_Filt.Clear

    Do While R_Orig(Idx, 1) <> ""

        If Not R_Orig(Idx, 1).EntireRow.Hidden Then
            R_Filt(Jdx, 1) = R_Orig(Idx, 1)
            Jdx = Jdx + 1
        End If

        Idx = Idx + 1
    Loop
    Range(R_Filt(1, 1), R_Filt(Jdx - 1, 1)).Name = R_Filt.Name.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: sorry this is a bit to advanced for me, I'm not the best in english can you please explain it a bit more detailed. I'm really sorry.. I'm not sure what i have to to at the moment...